# C# разный формат для положительных и отрицательных чисел, вывод цифр после запятой

Tags: c#

Мне нужно получить разное форматирование для чисел с разным знаком. Знаю, что такой функционал уже есть в C#, но он немного не подходит.

*Буду демонстрировать код выполнения из **C# Interactive**:*

```
> using System.Globalization;
. var en = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
. var arr = new[] { +10, -20, +0.05, -0.03, 1 / 3.0 };
```

Обычное форматирование:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("g", en)))
"10, -20, 0.05, -0.03, 0.333333333333333"
```

В качестве примера покажу формат с выводом знака:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("+0;-0", en)))
"+10, -20, +0, +0, +0"
```

Такой формат не пишет цифры после запятой и отнёс (-0.03) к положительным..
Пробую поменять формат, что бы выводил вещественную часть:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("+0.00;-0.00", en)))
"+10.00, -20.00, +0.05, -0.03, +0.33"
```

Уже лучше, но теперь выводит лишние нули для целых значений. Изменяю формат дальше:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("+0.##;-0.##", en)))
"+10, -20, +0.05, -0.03, +0.33"
```

Так намного лучше. Но что если мне потребуется вывести больше цифр после запятой? Ставить кучу (#)?

Вопрос, можно ли через описание собственного формата указывать более подробно, но ёмко, сколько цифр надо писать до/после запятой?

Было бы замечательно, что можно было бы совместить свой формат с уже имеющимися, как g, f и так далее:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("+g;-g", en)))
"+10, -20, +0.05, -0.03, +0.333333333333333"
```

Но увы такой способ выведет всего лишь:

```
> string.Join(", ", arr.Select(x=>x.ToString("+g;-g", en)))
"+g, -g, +g, +g, +g"
```

Comment: Во втором варианте отнёс (-0.03) к положительным потому что округлил до ноля, а ноль - считается положительным числом.

Comment: `Ставить кучу (#)?` Ну а почему бы и нет, если вам нужна определенная точность.